# Gridview tooltip not limiting column text to set amount of characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Tooltip set up on my gridview to only show the first 30 characters of text in my second column but it is not working. What am I missing?

```
  protected void GridView4_RowDataBound (object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                ViewState["OrigData"] = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;
                if (e.Row.Cells[1].Text.Length >= 30)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[1].Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Substring(0, 30) + "...";
                    e.Row.Cells[1].ToolTip = ViewState["OrigData"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is what the gridview looks like. I need that second column starting with the "0000000000000000000000012464...etc" to only show the first 30 characters.

[Example of gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w183.png)

Comment: Try e.Row.Cells[1].ToolTip = ViewState["OrigData"].ToString().Substring(0, 30) + "...";

Comment: that did not seem to make any difference